# Loading icon as background image loads

Tags: jquery, css

The background image takes some time to load.

How can I check if the background image (applied using the background-image CSS tag) has finished loading?

Comment: I'd suggest you to add a background color similar to the background image.That would create better user experience.

Comment: [jQuery Load Event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can include the loading icon as the default background image by default and then update the CSS via javascript once the slow-loading image has downloaded.

Here's a working example showing the technique:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imgSrc = 'https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3261/2801924702_ffbdeda927_d.jpg';
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    $("div").css("background-image", "url('" + img.src + "')");
  };
  img.src = imgSrc;
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 50px;
  color: purple;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>.
  <p>This div will have a solid color as background to begin with.</p>
  <p>Watch its background change to an image once it's loaded.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, your technique is great but this can be achieved only with CSS. CSS will dislay the color first and then the image when it has loaded. But to be adapted for a loading gif it can be a great technique :)